# GIT: How to trigger an npm script, after git push of particular file in the remote branch?

Tags: git, githooks, husky, git-husky

I have a requirement that once I push a csv file to remote branch, it should call an npm script to process the data from CSV file.

Please advice which would be the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Git does not have a post-push hook. There is a pre-receive hook that you can set up in the git server if you are using your own git server. You can read up on it here [Git hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)

Comment: Is post-update client side? Never used it, cause post-receive is server side. If it is client side then yes, that works

Comment: Server-side. The same as `pre-receive`.

Comment: Thanks, found an helpful link on post-merge, https://gist.github.com/GianlucaGuarini/8001627